# Всё(,) что надо сделать, переводят

Tags: пунктуация, придаточное-предложение, вставная-конструкция

В общем, есть предложение:

> Чаще всего здесь работают с цветовым пространством RGB, а всё,
>   что надо напечатать, переводят в CMYK.

Меня интересует запятая после "всё". Если рассматривать "что надо напечатать" как вставную конструкцию, получается, что смысл теряется: нельзя сказать "всё переводят в CMYK", потому что смысл от этого меняется. С другой стороны, конструкция похожа на обычное обособляемое придаточное. Что делать? Возможно ли, что тут неделимая конструкция?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Чаще всего здесь работают с цветовым пространством RGB, а всё, **что надо напечатать**, переводят в CMYK.*

Предложение оформлено верно, запятые нужны.

Вторая часть – это сложноподчиненное предложение (СПП) с придаточным местоименно-определительным.

Такие предложения надо **отличать от цельных по смыслу выражений** http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=146#pp146

Пример цельного по смыслу выражения подобной структуры: *Здесь можно купить **всё что** угодно.*  Обычно цельный оборот эквивалентен члену предложения и поэтому не выделяется запятыми.

Но: Здесь можно купить ***всё, что*** душе угодно.

При распространении цельного оборота он становится обычным придаточным предложением.

Comment: Скорее всего, под неделимой конструкцией имеется в виду цельное выражение (не требующее запятых).